# Transparet pixels are being pasted as black in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transparency

I paste an image with transparent pixels, but they are black in the final image

```
img = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), "white")

arbol16 = Image.open("arbol16.png")

img.paste(arbol16,( 0, 0, 16, 16))

img.show()
```

`arbol16.png` image file:

[image: contents of <code>arbol16.png</code> image file]

Comment: Due to the way image formats work, even 100% transparent pixels have an associated color, even if it's not used when rendering. Quite often, methods to view images don't handle the alpha well, so show the related colour instead. No idea if that's what you're hitting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're (understandably) being confused by what the `img.show()` is displaying — which I believe is wrong (and may in fact be a bug). On my Windows system a temporary .BMP image is displayed, and it looks like the transparent pixels are black.

[image: misleading result from <code>img.save()</code> call]

However if you add a line like `img.save('arbol16_mod.png')` at the end and then view *that* image file by manually opening it in some image file viewing program, such as Paint, Windows Photo Viewer, or Photoshop, the result is correct.

[image: correct results]

Answer (score 2):

The `paste` method does not take into account the alpha of the image it's pasting; you need to add a `mask` parameter to control that. If the image you're pasting is `RGBA` you can just pass it twice.

```
arbol16 = arbol16.convert("RGBA")
img.paste(arbol16, (0, 0, 16, 16), arbol16)
```