# When I create an image using PILLOW with color and paste it over another image, it turns black and white

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I create the object using the following code:

```
if size == 'L':
    W, H = (240,60)
elif size == 'M':
    W, H = (160,60)
elif size == 'S':
    W, H, = (80,60)

myFont = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 16)

cabinet = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H),"yellow")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(cabinet)
w, h = draw.textsize(name, font=myFont)
draw.text(((W-w)/2,(H-h)/2), name, fill="black", font=myFont)

cabinet.save('image.png','PNG')
```

I get the following image:
[image: CREATED IMAGE (IN COLOR)]

Then when I paste this image onto another image using the following code:

```
map = Image.open('PATH/TO/IMAGE.png')
back_im = map.copy()
back_im.paste(cabinet, (x, y))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(back_im)
back_im.save('PATH/TO/NEW.png', quality=100)
```

I get this image:
[image: PASTED ONTO IMAGE (COLOR IS LOST)]

I am wondering how to eliminate this issue of losing my color upon pasting and saving.

Comment: See [Transparet pixels are being pasted as black in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57948254/5987)

Comment: And using `quality=` on a PNG image won't do anything.  That parameter is really only for JPEG files.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  And P.S. try not to use Python keywords like `map` as variable names - it will bite you someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
imgNew = Image.new('RGB', (x,y), <>)
maps = Image.open('PATH/TO/IMAGE.png').convert("RGB")
imgNew.paste(maps, (x, y))
```

Comment: I added the .convert('RGB') and that fixed it! Thank you very much!